# Ошибка в window.on() после перехода на протокол https

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
c=window;
c.on("scrolled",this,this.onUpdate);
```

Вот такая конструкция. Раньше на сайте все работало прекрасно. Перешел на https - вылазит `alert` при загрузке страницы с ошибкой `MuseJSAssert: Error calling selector function:TypeError: $(...).registerOpacityScrollEffect is not a function`

Консоль выводит: `Uncaught TypeError: c.on is not a function`

Версия js - 2.x.x !

Ссылка на полный файл и сам сайт [https...](https://mlm-portal.ru/scripts/jquery.scrolleffects.js)

Как исправить ?

Comment: а как вы подключаете JQUERY на странице?

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer http://prntscr.com/9p2du0

Comment: ссылку на проект дайте еще).

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Добавил в вопрос

Comment: судя по всему вы хотели написать `$(window)` вместо `window`

Comment: @Grundy `c = $(window);` - не дало результата

Comment: @SlavikOkara, все еще _Uncaught TypeError: c.on is not a function_? или уже другая ошибка?

Comment: у вас в проекте для чего-то используются аж 3 версии jquery. Причем грузится и работает самая старая 1.4. Попробуйте по дефолту грузить вашу 2.x.x из папки /script

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Где вы увидели 1.4 ? Не могу найти.

Comment: @SlavikOkara http://joxi.ru/5md7zGDFv8QYKr

Comment: а что за `museutils`?

Comment: @Grundy Сам не знаю. Запутано все просто ****.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Удалил 1.4 поставил вместо него 2.2, теперь новая ошибка...

Comment: @Slavik Okara, попробуйте откатиться до jquery-1.8.3. Судя по логике включений до перехода на https исползовалась она. Хотя не исключено что возникнут другие проблемы

Comment: "попробуйте откатиться до jquery-1.8.3" - помогло. Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ вам и Grundy. Оформите ответом ? Я отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До перехода на протокол `https` нужную библиотеку включал скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') document.write('\x3Cscript src="http://musecdn.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
```

который в свою очередь грузил с другого сервера по `http` протоколу нужную версию библиотеки.

Т.к. Вам нельзя использовать более загрузку с других ресурсов по обычному протоколу, то решением может быть замена дефолтной версии с 1.4 на 1.8.3.

Приведенный выше скрипт можете удалить за ненадобностью.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы перешли на новую версию jQuery (2.2.0) в ней было множество изменений.
В частности: по сравнению с 1.4 удалено [свойство *browser*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

Судя по тому что подключенный файл *museutils.js* завязан на более раннюю версию, стоит либо вернуть ее, либо попробовать обновить *museutils.js*

Кроме того, после перехода на https, необходимо, чтобы все данные так же загружались с https, например, тот же youtube не покажет видео с http адресом

Comment: в частности изменить в файле museutils.js функцию Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit=function(){jQuery.browser.msie?(jQuery("html").addClass("ie"),jQuery.browser.version<8&&Muse.Utils.changeLItoDIVs()):jQuery.browser.SafariMobile&&jQuery("body").css("-webkit-text-size-adjust","none")};

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, подозреваю в новой версии файла это уже изменено, и кроме того менять в минифицированном файле это совсем крайний случай :-)

Comment: даже в минифицированном файле, я бы заменил алерт, на console.log))). Хотя пользоваться Muse это крайний случай..

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, я к тому, что этот файл может быть тупо сгенерированным этим muse, и, например, при следующем выкладывании он опять перезатрется и ошибка снова появится :-) с другой стороны, если это _конечная_ версия можно и так :-)